# How to fix the Camera issue in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-camera

I developed the android app using Camera.
The app works fine for all phones except Samsung.
When I open the camera in my app, the error is built in
mCamera.setParameters(params)

my code:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int wScreen = size.x;
int hScreen = size.y;

params.setPreviewSize(wScreen, hScreen);
params.setPictureSize(wScreen, hScreen);
params.setJpegQuality(100);
params.setRotation(90);
params.set("orientation", "portrait");
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

```
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size previewSize = sizes.get(0);

    params.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width,previewSize.height);
    params.setPictureSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    params.setRotation(90);
    params.set("orientation", "portrait");

    mCamera.setParameters(params);
```